# jQuery-Localize doesn't work for jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-localizer

I'm developing a PhoneGap web app with multiple languages and i'm using [jQuery-Localize](https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize/) to do. I got it running on a simple static page, but when I integrate it with jQuery-Mobile it doesn't works.

This is my simple test page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageHome">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#pageHome").live('pagecreate', function() {
        $("[rel*=localize]").localize("index");
    });
</script>
<div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
    <h3>Home</h3>
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#pageUne" rel="localize[one]" data-theme="" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-active">no</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pageTwo" rel="localize[two]" data-theme="" data-icon="star">no</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pageThree" rel="localize[three]" data-theme="a" data-icon="check">no</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content" data-role="content">
    <div><b>Welcome!</b></div>
</div>
```

I get in the PhoneGap console the next message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2

I tried to handle at events **pagebeforecreate** and **pageInit** without success

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer with example for your question
http://www.funcion13.com/2012/04/03/traduciendo-aplicaciones-de-jquery-mobile/

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for the answer in English, see this link:
https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize/issues/15

JQM adds lots of its own stuff to the DOM, so calling jquery-localize will destroy all of that work, leading to strange results. To work around it, call localize before JQM does its thing. An example from the above link:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','#home',function(event){
      $("[rel*=localize]").localize("index")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMLed.js is specifically developed for Jquery mobile. Light weight. Checkout the framework on GitHub [Link](https://nirus.github.com/HTMLed)

May be this helps!!